# PyBind11 - release memory created with new[]

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I have a PyBind project that includes a C library and their headers, and in there is a struct that points to memory that I need to allocate. The issue is that I have not figured out how to release the memory again at the end of the lifetime of the struct. My assumption was to `.def("__exit__")`, but it appears that is never called?

My library to reproduce this is at https://github.com/SinisterMJ/PyBindTest , and the code I thought I could use:

```
py::class_<Container>(mod, "Container")
    .def(py::init([]()
        { 
            Container* c = new Container();
            for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
                c->lineData[i] = new shortLine;
            return c;
        }))        
    .def("__exit__", [] (Container& obj) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
            delete obj.lineData[i];
     });
```

but the `__exit__` is never called (added a std::cout to verify).
How can I release the memory allocated by the struct?

When I run the test.py that creates the struct over and over just leaks the memory allocated

```
(0 : 34467840
100000 : 638394368
200000 : 1243406336
300000 : 1848147968
400000 : 2452889600
500000 : 3057631232
600000 : 3662372864
700000 : 4267384832
800000 : 4872126464
900000 : 5476868096
1000000 : 6081609728)
```

Comment: You're in C++, so use RAII principle. Make some wrapper class to hold/own the `Container*` and handle the resources automatically. Or perhaps a `shared_ptr` with a custom deleter will be sufficient.